# Why isn't this second table not visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables in a page like this:

```
<table style="width:800px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:400px;">
            <table id="currencies"
                style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:400px;">
            <table id="changers"
                style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use jqgrid to extend these. One is the master table while the other is the detail. The problem however is the second table (id = "changers") is not being displayed in the page. I inspected the javascript from the browser and it has only one `<td>` element within the table row. This problem goes away if I put them in separate tables like so:

```
<table id="currencies"
                style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px" />
<table id="changers"
                style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px" />
```

I'm totally stuck on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: err, isn't nesting tables allowed?

Comment: @ nakiya: Yes, but you said "I have two tables" and then presented markup containining *three*. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I had my heart in my mouth there for a moment. I have 2 days of experience in javascript. :)

Comment: sorry, but I couldn't see any relation of your question to jqGrid. Where is the corresponding code? If you use jqGrid you should specify properties of the table by jqGrid options. So you should use just *empty* `<table>` element having only `id` attribute. Instead of usage of outer table you can consider to use `<div>` elenebts

Comment: *Why isn't this second table not visible*. So it **is** visible, this second table?

Comment: @KooiInc: Yes it is visible (virtually) in the code. But not physically on the page. Let's split hairs. :)

Comment: @nakiya: reread your question: why **isn't** this second table **not** visible. It's like asking: *why is !!true true?*, right?

Comment: @KooiInc: gah. My bad. You win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two nested `table` tags aren't closed. The `<tag/>` form is **not** a shorthand form of `<tag></tag>`, it's purely for *void elements* like `<br/>` that don't ever have markup content (and also for *foreign elements*, details in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags)), and you only need the solidus (`/`) in XHTML (which I recommend avoiding unless you have a very specific need to use it, XHTML is fraught with peril and misconception).

Explicitly close the tables with `<table ...></table>` rather than `<table .../>`:

```
<table style="width:800px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:400px;">
            <table id="currencies"
                style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px"></table>
        </td>
        <td style="width:400px;">
            <table id="changers"
                style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The closing tags solve the problem! I will never get that hour of my life back :( Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add closing tags to your tables. Instead of this

```
<table />
```

do this

```
<table> </table>
```

The whole code:

```
<table style="width:800px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:400px;">
            <table id="currencies"
            style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px" ></table>
        </td>
        <td style="width:400px;">
            <table id="changers"
            style="border-spacing: 5px; padding: 3px; margin: 2px" ></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```